# Barnes-Hut N-Body In C Recursion

Tags: c, algorithm, math, recursion

I'm working on creating the barnes-hut algorithm for the n-body problem for a class.

I am constructing the tree as you see below, but after the the first iteration, upon the first recursion, it is supposed to cut the nodes up that contain bodies. It seems to be properly doing it, but I'm getting an issue where the bodies appear to be in the right quadrants, but the algorithm isn't putting them there. Can someone take a look? I'm going crazy, and it may be because I'm relatively new to C programming. The quadrants go in clockwise order.

```
struct Node * buildBHTree(double xmin, double xmax, double ymin, double ymax, struct Body *listOfBodies)
{
if (listOfBodies == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}
else if (listOfBodies->next == NULL)
{
    struct Node *singleNode = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    initNewNode(singleNode);
    singleNode->xmin = xmin;
    singleNode->xmax = xmax;
    singleNode->ymin = ymin;
    singleNode->ymax = ymax;
    singleNode->body = listOfBodies;
    //calculateCenterOfMassForNode(singleNode);
    return singleNode;
}
else
{
    struct Node *list1 = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    initNewNode(list1);
    list1->xmin = (xmin + xmax)/2;
    list1->xmax = xmax;
    list1->ymin = (ymin + ymax)/2;
    list1->ymax = ymax;

    struct Node *list2 = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    initNewNode(list2);
    list2->xmin = (xmin + xmax)/2;
    list2->xmax = xmax;
    list2->ymin = ymin;
    list2->ymax = (ymin + ymax)/2;

    struct Node *list3 = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    initNewNode(list3);
    list3->xmin = xmin;
    list3->xmax = (xmin + xmax)/2;
    list3->ymin = ymin;
    list3->ymax = (ymin + ymax)/2;

    struct Node *list4 = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    initNewNode(list4);
    list4->xmin = xmin;
    list4->xmax = (xmin + xmax)/2;
    list4->ymin = (ymin + ymax)/2;
    list4->ymax = ymax;

    //printf("xpos: %f | ypos: %f\n", listOfBodies->pos_x, listOfBodies->pos_y);
    printf("QUADRANT 1: xmin: %f | xmax: %f | ymin: %f | ymax: %f\n", list1->xmin, list1->xmax, list1->ymin, list1->ymax);
    printf("QUADRANT 2: xmin: %f | xmax: %f | ymin: %f | ymax: %f\n", list2->xmin, list2->xmax, list2->ymin, list2->ymax);
    printf("QUADRANT 3: xmin: %f | xmax: %f | ymin: %f | ymax: %f\n", list3->xmin, list3->xmax, list3->ymin, list3->ymax);
    printf("QUADRANT 4: xmin: %f | xmax: %f | ymin: %f | ymax: %f\n", list4->xmin, list4->xmax, list4->ymin, list4->ymax);

    struct Body *rootBodyReference = (struct Body *) malloc(sizeof(struct Body));
    rootBodyReference = listOfBodies;
    while (listOfBodies->next != NULL)
    {
        //QUADRANT 1
        if (listOfBodies->pos_x >= list1->xmin &&
            listOfBodies->pos_x <= list1->xmax &&
            listOfBodies->pos_y >= list1->ymin &&
            listOfBodies->pos_y <= list1->ymax)
        {
            printf("FOUND IN QUADRANT 1\n");
            addBodyToLinkedList(list1, listOfBodies);
        }
        //QUADRANT 2
        else if (listOfBodies->pos_x >= list2->xmin &&
                 listOfBodies->pos_x <= list2->xmax &&
                 listOfBodies->pos_y <= list2->ymin &&
                 listOfBodies->pos_y >= list2->ymax)
        {
            printf("FOUND IN QUADRANT 2\n");
            addBodyToLinkedList(list2, listOfBodies);
        }
        //QUADRANT 3
        else if (listOfBodies->pos_x >= list3->xmin &&
                 listOfBodies->pos_x <= list3->xmax &&
                 listOfBodies->pos_y <= list3->ymin &&
                 listOfBodies->pos_y >= list3->ymax)
        {
            printf("FOUND IN QUADRANT 3\n");
            addBodyToLinkedList(list3, listOfBodies);
        }
        //QUADRANT 4
        else if (listOfBodies->pos_x >= list4->xmin &&
                 listOfBodies->pos_x <= list4->xmax &&
                 listOfBodies->pos_y >= list4->ymin &&
                 listOfBodies->pos_y <= list4->ymax)
        {
            printf("FOUND IN QUADRANT 4\n");
            addBodyToLinkedList(list4, listOfBodies);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("NO PLACE FOR THIS BODY WITH POSITION X: %f AND POSITION Y: %f\n", listOfBodies->pos_x, listOfBodies->pos_y);
        }

        listOfBodies = listOfBodies->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
    listOfBodies = rootBodyReference;

    bringNodeListBackToHeadNode(list1);
    bringNodeListBackToHeadNode(list2);
    bringNodeListBackToHeadNode(list3);
    bringNodeListBackToHeadNode(list4);

    struct Node *nodeTemp0 = buildBHTree(list1->xmin, list1->xmax, list1->ymin, list1->ymax, list1->body);
    struct Node *nodeTemp1 = buildBHTree(list2->xmin, list2->xmax, list2->ymin, list2->ymax, list2->body);
    struct Node *nodeTemp2 = buildBHTree(list3->xmin, list3->xmax, list3->ymin, list3->ymax, list3->body);
    struct Node *nodeTemp3 = buildBHTree(list4->xmin, list4->xmax, list4->ymin, list4->ymax, list4->body);

    struct Node *nodeTemp = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    nodeTemp->body = listOfBodies;
    nodeTemp->node1 = nodeTemp0;
    nodeTemp->node2 = nodeTemp1;
    nodeTemp->node3 = nodeTemp2;
    nodeTemp->node4 = nodeTemp3;
    nodeTemp->xmin = xmin;
    nodeTemp->xmax = xmax;
    nodeTemp->ymin = ymin;
    nodeTemp->ymax = ymax;

    return nodeTemp;
}
}
```

I'm also consistently getting the following output when this runs (Note that the first print out is upon the first run, and the second is when the recursion reruns the method for the first time):

```
QUADRANT 1: xmin: 0.000000 | xmax: 250000000000.000000 | ymin: 0.000000 | ymax: 250000000000.000000
QUADRANT 2: xmin: 0.000000 | xmax: 250000000000.000000 | ymin: -250000000000.000000 | ymax: 0.000000
QUADRANT 3: xmin: -250000000000.000000 | xmax: 0.000000 | ymin: -250000000000.000000 | ymax: 0.000000
QUADRANT 4: xmin: -250000000000.000000 | xmax: 0.000000 | ymin: 0.000000 | ymax: 250000000000.000000
FOUND IN QUADRANT 1
FOUND IN QUADRANT 1
FOUND IN QUADRANT 1
FOUND IN QUADRANT 1
FOUND IN QUADRANT 1

QUADRANT 1: xmin: 125000000000.000000 | xmax: 250000000000.000000 | ymin: 125000000000.000000 | ymax: 250000000000.000000
QUADRANT 2: xmin: 125000000000.000000 | xmax: 250000000000.000000 | ymin: 0.000000 | ymax: 125000000000.000000
QUADRANT 3: xmin: 0.000000 | xmax: 125000000000.000000 | ymin: 0.000000 | ymax: 125000000000.000000
QUADRANT 4: xmin: 0.000000 | xmax: 125000000000.000000 | ymin: 125000000000.000000 | ymax: 250000000000.000000
NO PLACE FOR THIS BODY WITH POSITION X: 0.000000 AND POSITION Y: 0.000000
NO PLACE FOR THIS BODY WITH POSITION X: 57900000000.000000 AND POSITION Y: 0.000000
NO PLACE FOR THIS BODY WITH POSITION X: 108200000000.000000 AND POSITION Y: 0.000000
NO PLACE FOR THIS BODY WITH POSITION X: 149600000000.000000 AND POSITION Y: 0.000000
```

Comment: Please try to provide a minimal code example reproducing your error. Can we be sure that your lists are working as they should? Did you test them?

Comment: @DanielJour I have tested the lists, they are operating as they should. What code would you need to see?

Comment: @DanielJour The above code is the code that is ran, and should run recursively. But when the recursion is called, it should replot the bodies based on their X/Y coordinates in the new quadrant coordinates. Clearly by my example, they are within the bounds, but it is not placing them in that list because the method is thinking the bodies are not within those bounds for some reason.

Comment: Asking others to debug for you is not very good, but still acceptable in stackoverflow (I think). However, please at least post the COMPLETE code ... (e.g. `initNewNode`, `addBodyToLinkedList`, `bringNodeListBackToHeadNode`, etc.) There can be a bug anywhere.

Comment: @WhatsUp I know how to post on stackoverflow. In this case, I knew specifically where the issue was, and only showed the code that was needed.

Comment: You shouldn't be using recursion for this. When you start to reach millions of particles the code will be impossible to run. You should always make this procedures iterable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is that some checks are off, like in here

```
    //QUADRANT 2
    else if (listOfBodies->pos_x >= list2->xmin &&
             listOfBodies->pos_x <= list2->xmax &&
             listOfBodies->pos_y <= list2->ymin && // should be >=
             listOfBodies->pos_y >= list2->ymax)   // should be <=
    {
        printf("FOUND IN QUADRANT 2\n");
        addBodyToLinkedList(list2, listOfBodies);
    }
```

Second issue is that you are not handling special cases, where the quadrants collide

```
QUADRANT 1: xmin: 0.0 | xmax: 250000000000.0  | ymin: 0.0 | ymax: 250000000000.0
QUADRANT 2: xmin: 0.0 | xmax: 250000000000.0  | ymin: -250000000000.0 | ymax: 0.0
QUADRANT 3: xmin: -250000000000.0 | xmax: 0.0 | ymin: -250000000000.0 | ymax: 0.0
QUADRANT 4: xmin: -250000000000.0 | xmax: 0.0 | ymin: 0.0 | ymax: 250000000000.0
```

Because your checks are all inclusive, the point `0,0` exist in all 4 quadrants, to fix this, you can consider min values as inclusive while max as exclusive, like this

```
    //QUADRANT 1
    if (listOfBodies->pos_x >= list1->xmin &&
        listOfBodies->pos_x <  list1->xmax &&
        listOfBodies->pos_y >= list1->ymin &&
        listOfBodies->pos_y <  list1->ymax)
    {
        printf("FOUND IN QUADRANT 1\n");
        addBodyToLinkedList(list1, listOfBodies);
    }
```

My suggestion is that you can use two `int` *(to represent the decimal part & the integer part)* instead of `double` to enhance performance and avoiding issues when comparing floating-point numbers.